# UIImage implementation / paging?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

From the UIImage documentation:

> In low-memory situations, image data may be purged from a UIImage
>   object to free up memory on the system. This purging behavior affects
>   only the image data stored internally by the UIImage object and not
>   the object itself. When you attempt to draw an image whose data has
>   been purged, the image object automatically reloads the data from its
>   original file.

What about UIImages that were not loaded from a file, but instead drawn, say, with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext()?

I'm trying to come up with ways to optimize the memory usage of UITableViewCells with UIImageViews containing UIImages as the cells enter and are pulled from the reuse queue.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

My understanding is that CGImage data is gone, so I think (this for your custom drawn image point) you are out of luck?

I actually just dealt with a similar issue with UITableViews. One thing that I did for performance was to create cells with a Nib; this was the single largest boost in performance of all the things I did, so if you are not using a Nib consider it.

You might also consider some form of preloading if you have that much data. I don't know what you are trying to implement, so this may or may be applicable.

One other note, after purging UIImage's reloading them from their files is a significant memory hit, so if you are at that point you really need to just look at memory usage overall.